# Querying postgrest with httpx

Tags: python, urlencode, httpx, postgrest

Consider the first "Operator Modifiers" example from https://postgrest.org/en/stable/references/api/tables_views.html#operator-modifiers:

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/people?last_name=like(any).{O*,P*}"
```

If I try to replicate it using `httpx` (or `requests`, `urllib3` or any other Python module I tried) the URL that ends up at `PostgREST`'s end is urlencoded:

```
>>> import https
>>> r = httpx.get("http://localhost:3000/people?last_name=like(any).{O*,P*}")
>>> print(r.url)
URL('http://localhost:3000/people?last_name=like(any).%7BO*,P*%7D')
```

`PostgREST` responds with an error to that:

```
{'code': '22P02',
 'details': 'Expected ":", but found "}".',
 'hint': None,
 'message': 'invalid input syntax for type json'}
```

It does not seem possible to disable the automatic urlencoding on the client's end.

How can I query `PostgREST` using `httpx`?

Comment: What is the SQL type of `last_name`? This error appears on `jsonb` columns AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here has nothing to do with URL encoding. URL encoding is required by the standard, and if postgrest actually had a problem with that it would be buggy.

The problem is that your `curl` command line doesn't do what you think it does.

`curl` treats a `{a,b,c}` expression a bit like the shell: it will expand it into multiple distinct URLs. So when you write:

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/people?last_name=like(any).{O*,P*}"
```

Your are effectively running multiple `curl` commands:

```
curl "http://localhost:3000/people?last_name=like(any).O*"
curl "http://localhost:3000/people?last_name=like(any).P*"
```

This is described in the "Globbing" section of [the curl man page](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html).

I think you will find that you can request either of the above URLs using `httpx` (etc) without a problem.

---

You can verify the above by running `curl` with the `--trace-ascii log` option, and then inspecting the resulting `log` file. You will see multiple `GET` requests.

You can disable globbing with the `--globoff` (`-g`) option.

Comment: Sorry for the late followup but does that mean that writing more complex PostgREST queries will lead to more and more requests being needed to get the results? Or is the example on their page wrong? The HTTP GET example uses the same curly braces and really is one single request.